# SparkR - list of files for a AWS mounted bucket

Tags: directory, sparkr

I just started working with Spark R. There is a aws.s3 bucket that is mounted in Databricks.

I would like to use list.files() or dir() to list files that contain certain pattern in their names. However, I can't detect the path for that. I can read a single file with sparkr::read.df, but I don't know how to find all the files out of sevral thousands that I am interested in the bucket?

Many thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. There is an R package called aws.s3 that can help you with that here: https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3

OR, if you have the aws command line tool installed, you could do a call to it via `system` from within R. You could include a `grep` in the call and do something like

`listOfBucketsWithABCpattern<- system("aws s3 ls | grep abc", intern=TRUE)`

Just to clarify, this isn't a `SparkR` question so much as it is an `R` question and an `AWS Command Line Interface` question.

Hopefully this helps. Cheers!